# How to find eigenvectors given the eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy, math

Having a large matrix, I need to compute its eigenvectors. I have an analytical way to compute its eigenvectors and I want to know if is there any fast way to compute these vectors. (Direct solutions using scipy / numpy are not feasible. Also, my matrix is not sparse )

Edit : 
Matrix I'm interested in are gene expressions, thus, matrix size is between 10.000 and 100.000

I use python as my main language. Using numpy to solve (M - lambda*Ip)x = 0 gives 0 as a solution ( which is still correct )

Comment: All talk and no code is an ideology not welcomed at Stack Overflow. Please provide your research effort of what you've done so far.

Comment: You may want to look [here](http://scikit-bio.org/docs/0.5.4/generated/generated/skbio.stats.ordination.pcoa.html).

Comment: If you already know the eigenvalue `lambda`, then the corresponding eigenvector is the solution `v` of the linear system `(M - lambda * I) * v = 0`. You will get at least one degree of freedom that corresponds to the length of the eigenvector. If an eigenvalue occurs multiple times, you get more.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it would probably help others help you if you would say more about stuff like, how big is this matrix anyway, do you need to solve this problem more than once, from where did it come, does the matrix have some special structure, etc.